# How to interupt typing text in terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, printing, keyboard, pynput

I'm trying to make a little RPG game and I came up with the following idea:

The idea is simpel:

**1.** Class Typing would print text like it's being typed on screen.

*(A function would be easier to write, but the problem would be the same)*

```
import sys
import os
import time


class Typing:
    def __init__(self, text, speed):
        self.text = text
        self.speed = speed

        for l in text:
            sys.stdout.write(l)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(speed)
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()


text = '''
                         _____ __             __  
                        / ___// /_____ ______/ /__
                        \__ \/ __/ __ `/ ___/ //_/
                       ___/ / /_/ /_/ / /__/ ,<   
   ____               /____/\__/\__,_/\___/_/|_|  
  / __ \_   _____  _____/ ____/ ____ _      __    
 / / / | | / / _ \/ ___/ /_  / / __ | | /| / /    
/ /_/ /| |/ /  __/ /  / __/ / / /_/ | |/ |/ /     
\____/ |___/\___/_/  /_/   /_/\____/|__/|__/      

'''
Typing(text, 0.005)
```

**2.** By pressing the keyboard key **'space'**, the for-loop would stop and the full text would be shown on screen.

```
        for l in text:

            # Keyboard would listen for the key 'space'

            # if 'space' key is detected:
            #     os.system('clear)
            #     print(text)

            # Keyboard would stop listing for the key 'space'
            #     break

            sys.stdout.write(l)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(speed)
        sys.stdout.write('\n')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

My question:

Is this even possible in Python? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, there's a [keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/#description) in Python. Add `if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):`. You may want to include a small amount of delay  after the condition is satisfied, otherwise seemly one key press will be read as several many.

Comment: Thank you Vinicius. That is exactly what I was looking for.